# tasker with state "cell near" and several cell towers with almost the same number

Tags: android, automation, tasker

I use tasker and the state "cell near" to get battery friendly location information. If I have a closer look at the found cell towers, I get a lot of these (anonymised):

```
GSM:11111.22222222
GSM:11111.22222202
GSM:11111.22222022
GSM:11111.22122222
...
```

So, the the first digits (the cell tower id ?) and after the dot follows a number that is almost but not the same. I have to relearn the "new" towers regularly. Isn't it possible to use some kind of wildcards like

```
GSM:11111.*
```

to match all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

afaik, use of wildcards is not allowed. The only option with `cell near` is to run the scan and then leave the phone for 10-20 minutes and / or move it (while scanning) around the location where you want to have detailed cell information.

What you could do, however, is to set another profile trigger (i.e. wifi near) and in the task, enclose the desired actions within an `if` statement, where as parameter you'd set `%CELLID` to match regex